# Converting list of lists into JSON Object

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python.
I have a file which is basically a list of sub-lists. Each sub-list is comprised of 4 elements, I need to  convert it into JSON object in the following format: Each element of the sublists [1,2,3,4] needs to be prefixed with four keys (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) that is the first element will be prefixed with Col1, second element with Col2, third with Col3, fourth with Col4.
Now the loop will read the next sublist and prefix these columns with elements of the second sublist elements in the similar fashion, and so on till the list does not ends.

Following is the how the file looks :

> [[2004732899, 96, 0, 1], [2004732917, 96, 1, 1], [2004732949, 96, 2,
>   1], [2004732967, 96, 3, 1], [2004733201, 96, 4, 1], [2004733215, 96,
>   5, 1], [2004733251, 96, 6, 1], [2004733265, 96, 7, 1], [2004733399,
>   96, 8, 1], [2004733417, 96, 9, 1].....]

Following is desired:

```
{
 {
   'Col1':2004732899,
   'Col2':96, 
   'Col3':0,
   'Col4':1
                  }
{
   'Col1':2004732917,
   'Col2':96, 
   'Col3':1,
   'Col4':1
                  }

{
   'Col1':2004732949,
   'Col2':96, 
   'Col3':2,
   'Col4':1
                  }
.....
}
```

I have been searching in JSON Decoder. JSON dump, but not able to find a proper method to do this.
Any help is a great help.

Comment: thanks for the reply! yeah somewhat similar to what you wrote! Actually I want a json objects which will have fixed keys or field names which are Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, and Col 4 and each column will have the each element of the sublists of the list, so basically every row would represent a sublist. Please share your answer.

Comment: did you found the answer? If yes, can you tell me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output isn't valid JSON because instead of an outer list '[' you have an outer dictionary '{' which is not valid in this case because inside the outer list there is a list of dictionaries, not key/value pairs.

Since your file input is valid JSON you can `load()` it from your file which will convert it from a string in a file to a list. Then you use `dumps()` to convert the list into what you're asking for:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('/tmp/listsublists') as f:
...     a = json.load(f)    # This just converts the string into a list
...
>>> json.dumps([{"Col1": b[0], "Col2": b[1], "Col3": b[2], "Col3": b[3]} for b in a])
```

This prints a JSON string that has the following contents (I formatted the JSON here):

```
[
   {
      "Col1":2004732899,
      "Col2":96,
      "Col3":0,
      "Col4":1
   },
   {
      "Col1":2004732917,
      "Col2":96,
      "Col3":1,
      "Col4":1
   },
   {
      "Col1":2004732949,
      "Col2":96,
      "Col3":2,
      "Col4":1
   }
]
```